# Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractConnector

Tags: java, spring, jmx, simplejmx

I have got `Spring` project. I need to use `JMX`. I am using `simplejmx` - I found it really useful but unfortunately, I cannot manage few, basic things.

I wrote a really simple server:

```
package com.pckg.jmx;

import com.j256.simplejmx.web.JmxWebServer;

public class JMXServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JmxWebServer jmxWebServer = new JmxWebServer(8123);
        jmxWebServer.start();
    }

}
```

with `pom.xml`:

```
<project...> 

    <properties>
        <jetty-version>8.1.9.v20130131</jetty-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.j256.simplejmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>simplejmx</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I run it, it works well. I want to do it in Spring way. I created `jmx-config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- publishes classes that have @JmxResource or implement JmxSelfNaming 
        to jmxServer automagically -->
    <bean id="beanPublisher" class="com.j256.simplejmx.spring.BeanPublisher">
        <property name="jmxServer" ref="jmxServer" />
    </bean>

    <!-- our JmxServer which publishes our beans via JMX -->
    <bean id="jmxServer" class="com.j256.simplejmx.web.JmxWebServer"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <!-- the port should probably come from a configured property -->
        <property name="registryPort" value="8123" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I changed `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    ...
    jmx-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I added simple class:

```
package com.pckg.jmx;

import com.j256.simplejmx.common.JmxResource;

@JmxResource
public class DummyJMX {

    private int var = 3;
}
```

When I run my application I see warnings:

```
10:15:07,184 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Servlet3Continuation$1 due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Servlet3Continuation$1
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]

10:15:07,191 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Servlet3Continuation$2 due to exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Servlet3Continuation$2
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentDescription$DefaultComponentConfigurator.configure(ComponentDescription.java:606)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

and an exception (it is too long, I pasted only first part):

```
10:16:54,674 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-13) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanPublisher' defined in class path resource [jmx-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractConnector
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) [spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) [spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628) [spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:3.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractConnector
```

I was looking for a solution but I cannot fix it problem. My idea is that the problem is with `pom.xml` but I am not sure, moreover, I have no idea how to check it and what I should change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the jetty-server dependency as optional and if you are packaging the code as war, it may be possible (depending on what other plugins and configuration settings you have in your pom) that jar not to be included in it.
Check the resulting war file and test the packaging without `<optional>true</optional>` in your pom for 'jetty-server' dependency.

Comment: Hi, I removed `<optional>` and now I have got another error. Anyhow, you fixed this problem, so I gonna close this question and I will try to fix another bug.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrei Stefan answer solved this problem but anyhow, there is also another problem.

```
<bean id="jmxServer" class="com.j256.simplejmx.web.JmxWebServer"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <!-- the port should probably come from a configured property -->
    <property name="registryPort" value="8123" />
</bean>
```

There is no field `registryPort` in `com.j256.simplejmx.web.JmxWebServer`: [Class JmxWebServer](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/javadoc/simplejmx/com/j256/simplejmx/web/JmxWebServer.html). It should be like this:

```
<bean id="jmxServer" class="com.j256.simplejmx.web.JmxWebServer"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <!-- the port should probably come from a configured property -->
    <property name="serverPort" value="8123" />
</bean>
```

I hope this will help somone in the future